# The unusual layout of the text on the html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, markup

I have text in Word document and I want publish it to web.

The page should be no vertical scrolling. All content must be broken into pages (no more than the height of the screen) to further flip through horizontally. There is an idea to wrap each paragraph in div.paragraph. When the page loads runs over all div.paragraph and add them to div.page (h = height of the window), if it has enough space in height. But in this case I do not know what to do with tables that do not fit on the screen height.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I'll try to describe again what I want. I apologize for my English.

In the Word document I have a text that I can scroll vertically, but in HTML I need to break apart the text content of which does not exceed the height of the window, and that they may have to scroll horizontally, as if you are viewing magazine.

Example: http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/steve-jobs/20

Answer (score 3):

Convert to pdf, upload on google docs, embed the iframe.

Comment: It's clear from the way the question is horrifically worded that OP doesn't know what he's doing & I don't think posting his existing code would help. So **+1** for this, might has well not mess about.